# Getting PPPD to log successful CHAP authentication

Tags: vpn, point-to-point-protocol

I've successfully set up an OpenSwan L2TP/IPsec VPN.  PPP is used to authenticate the peer (via CHAP) and set up the virtual network interface, and that works well.  My question: how can I cause pppd to write *who* logged in to syslog?  I can tell who the unsuccessful logins are from, but not the successful ones.

Answer (score 0):

See the [pppd manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pppd), you can either:

1. Run it with the "debug" option.
2. SIGUSR1 acts as a toggle for debugging messages. The syntax for sending a signal to a process is `"kill -s USR1 [process ID]"`, you can get the process ID using the `ps` command.

Do note:

- Both methods require you to edit /etc/syslog.conf accordingly so it shows debug level messages.
- Both methods show a lot more than just successful logins, it will show all valid control packets sent or received.